# Alter Add to Cart form POST data provided by #action

Tags: 7, forms

I am going to be phasing out Drupal Commerce on our website in favor of a new custom built application that is hosted at another URL. Without completely rebuilding everything I am trying to override the Add to Cart form to redirect with POST data to the new app.

Using $form['#action'] I can redirect properly and dumping out shows something like this:

```
array(7) {
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(4) "8566"
    ["form_build_id"]=>
    string(48) "form--90fc5Yp9qgp4CVFJlq03jfEZyYBkAhDX-j7E5g9oBQ"
    ["form_token"]=>
    string(43) "T08Fl1dNHuI4BCZ4JuLNwxbw6gUTOfnodbc1zcQMR4E"
    ["form_id"]=>
    string(35) "commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_8566"
    ["field_are_you_a_product"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
            ["field_are_you_a_"]=>
            array(1) {
                ["und"]=>
                string(3) "yes"
            }
        }
    }
    ["op"]=>
        string(11) "Add to cart"
```

This is helpful but the product_id is useless as I need more info, like the SKU or a custom ID field I have on the product level. I can't seem to get this to provide me with the product info I need.

I initially tried using a custom submit handler instead but that didn't work. drupal_http_request isn't right as it just sends post data, does actually redirect with post data like action does.

So since setting the action works great, how would I alter this form to send more information during that step within hook_form_alter?

Comment: you can use `commerce_product_load($product_id)` 
 to load product object, than you can retrieve any info see the fuction http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/commerce/modules--product--commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_load/7

Comment: Yes sorry should have included that. I can use that no problem. However storing that information where it is added to post is a problem. Seems that add to cart only submits some information and not all the form data.

Comment: the dump above is the $form_state or $form ?

Comment: That dump is from my external site within $_REQUEST.

Comment: I think you should add other fields to your form, in the `hook_form_alter` for example  SKU `$form['sky'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => YOUR_VALUE,
);`  as hidden fields and they will submitted with the form

Comment: Ah that could work, I’ll try that later and see if it submits. Thanks!

Comment: it will work, hidden fields submitted just like other ones

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was skeptical because if you dump the $form before submitting there are hidden fields already that don't get sent, so just adding another hidden field didn't make sense that it would work when others didn't. You should rewrite your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Ok I will post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other fields to your form as hiden, in the `hook_form_alter` for example add SKU field as hidden.

```
  $form['sky'] = [
    '#type'  => 'hidden',
    '#value' => YOUR_VALUE,
  ];
```

Hidden fields will submitted like others.